# Android custom animation

Tags: android, animation, android-canvas

I'm creating a custom spinner which I need to animate. The spinner consists of about 10 shapes which I draw using Canvas and Paths. Each shape should be animated separately and each shape is drawn at a separate time. Every so often a new shape is drawn while the rest are still going through their animation cycle, so you get from animating one shape to 10 and then your reverse back to 0.

I have this working now by drawing these shapes inside the onDraw method. onDraw is called every time I invalidate() and invalidate() is called from a recursive method with a postDelay() every 40ms to get the desired animation. This all kinda works however I can see the CPU use rising drastically and after about 10-15 seconds the whole thing grinds to a halt. So something is clearly going wrong.. Possibly that's not even the right way of attempting animation at all.

I guess my questions are - what do you think is going wrong and why? Also what would be the right approach for animating things on canvas?

edit:

[image: CPU usage levels]

edit2:

Looks like my drastic CPU usage was coming from reusing Path objects. Not really sure why, but forgoing reuse of objects and recreating them between onDraw methods has drastically increased the performance. The CPU usage still climbs up to about 5-10% in about 10-15 minutes of running the spinner animation but that's nothing like the previous 60-80% I was experiencing inside a minute.

Comment: I wouldn't do a postDelayed, I'd use choreographer.    But most likely you just have a very inefficient onDraw method.  Are you double buffering and minimizing redraws as much as you can?

Comment: Can't use choreographer as targeting API 11. onDraw could be inefficient - I'm drawing all shapes each time as their opacity change every 40ms.. getting opacity from an array list which gets calculated before invalidate() is called..

Comment: If all that's changing is their opacity, pre tender ask the shapes to in memory bitmaps. Then just blit then to the canvas with the proper opacity each time

Comment: If I understood you correctly you suggest I draw the shapes, save them as bitmaps in memory, then on each draw I change each of the bitmaps opacity? Maybe you know some code or tutorial that would help me?

Comment: Also if I create the bitmaps with shapes and change the opacity later, won't this change the opacity of the whole bitmap rather than the actual shape I drew with drawPath()?

Comment: Look for AnimationDrawable. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html